# Excel - Blanks show up as zeros in Index/small code

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble figuring this out, I've inserted an `IF` statement into my code but my fields are still showing 0's where there are blanks in my table.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Error'!$A$2:$I$5000,SMALL(IF('Error'!$E$2:$E$5000="","",IF(OR('Error'!$E$2:$E$5000="does
not match",'Error'!$A$2:$I$5000="not on the
Route"),ROW('Error'!$A$2:$A$5000))),ROW(2:2))-1,1),"")
```

Edited to include [expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwLYg.png) and [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Nwy.png)

Comment: You seem to be checking a range in you if condition : `IF('Error'!$E$2:$E$5000="", [true], [false]` the range will never be equal to "". I think you would have a better result with the `VLOOKUP()` function of by comparing only one cell in your formula

Comment: I've tried other things, such as changing the IF('Error'!$E$2:$E$5000="" to IF('Error'!$E$2:$E$5000=0.  I've also tried looking for this condition as a secondary condition rather than the 1st.  Using a vlookup is no good as I need to skip line items that don't meet my conditions, or perhaps I'm just not knowledgeable enough to make the vlookup function perform this task

Comment: could you provide data samples or a quick mock up of your sheets and of the expected result please?

Comment: I've edited my original question to include pictures of my expected results and table

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you want : you want a formula where if the column E has one empty cell, to display empty in the result of the formula?

Comment: thats correct :)

Comment: try the `COUNTBLANK()` function like this : `=IF(COUNTBLANK('Error'!$E$2:$E$5000) > 0, "at least one is empty", "no empty cell")`

Comment: Ha!  As much banging my head as I've done with this formula, I've figured it out.  A light bulb finally went off, I'll post the answer here in a second :)  Thanks Sirmyself for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose of your function is to determine if at least one cell in your range is empty, you can use the COUNTBLANK() function like this :

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK('Error'!$E$2:$E$5000) > 0, "at least one is empty", "no empty cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the condition at the very beginning of the code to make this work, so there are now essentially two index/small conditions.  Blank values now populate as expected.

```
{=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Error Report'!$A$2:$I$5000,SMALL(IF(OR('Error Report'!$E$2:$E$5000="Dealer does not match the shipment",'Error Report'!$A$2:$I$5000="Dealer ID is not on the Route"),ROW('Error Report'!$A$2:$A$5000)),ROW(4:4))-1,1)="","",INDEX('Error Report'!$A$2:$I$5000,SMALL(IF(OR('Error Report'!$E$2:$E$5000="Dealer does not match the shipment",'Error Report'!$A$2:$I$5000="Dealer ID is not on the Route"),ROW('Error Report'!$A$2:$A$5000)),ROW(4:4))-1,1)),"")}
```